# Using a Dojo theme

Tags: css, dojo

I am trying to make a simple login page with dojo, I have a button at the moment but it doesn't use the dojo theme. The css works when I copy everything from the theme of claro and make a local css file but it doesn't work when i try to load it from the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<title>Button test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css ">
</head> 
<script src="lib/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

         <body class="claro">


        <script>

            require(["dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/SimpleTextarea", "dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!"]);
        </script>
    </body>

         <body class="claro">
        <button id="Button" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"
            data-dojo-props="
                iconClass: 'dijitIconNewTask',
                showLabel: false,
                onClick: function(){ console.log('Second button was clicked!'); }">
            Login

        </button>

    </html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors that you are seeing when loading the css file?

Comment: Nope no error messages, I also found out that the script to load dojo has to be in the body and not in the head, the theme still doesn't load though.

Comment: Hmmm try doing this without the multiple body tags and see if that's what's causing the problem. Not quite sure why you have multiple body tags and why one of them isn't closed out properly.

Comment: @Richard also not sure as to why he/she's loading Dojo twice, one from CDN and one local. ?!